# Is there a better way to test :admin security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am going through Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  I'm up to the first exercise of 9.6, where he asks me to test that the User `admin` attribute isn't accessible.  The justification is earlier in the book:

After [Listing 9.42](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-attr_accessible_review), Hartl's Rails Tutorial says

> If we omitted the attr_accessible list in the User model (or foolishly added :admin to the list), a malicious user could send a PUT request as follows:
>
> `put /users/17?admin=1`

The corresponding exercise ([exercise 9.6.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-updating_deleting_exercises)) in the tutorial says

> add a test to verify that the User admin attribute isn’t accessible

**I have completed that test** with this code in `user_spec.rb`:

```
expect do
  @user.update_attributes(:admin => true)
end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
```

But I used stackoverflow to get that test.  **This was my original idea** (in `user_pages_spec.rb`):

```
expect do
    put user_path(user) + "?admin=1"
end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error) # or some other error
```

**But I couldn't get it to work.**

So my questions are:

1. **Is my idea possible?** Isn't it better to test directly for what a potential hacker might do from the command line?  Isn't that the idea of Capybara, testing user actions?
2. **If it is possible, is there a difference between testing mass assignment and testing the PUT action?**
3. **If it isn't possible, why?**  Is it just not necessary or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would argue with you that your test is actually better. Some would argue that the given answer is testing Rails functionality which really isn't your job. However, I do think it's frequently good to test things in several different directions.

I was under the impression from back in my school days that it was impossible to send data via the URI except when doing a GET. A quick search of stackoverflow didn't result in any confirmation. However, the wikipedia article seems to imply it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%2

I think the correct line of code would be

```
put user_path(user), {user: {admin: 1}, id: user.id}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help and good to know I'm not bonkers (yeah it did feel I was testing rails functionality).

I've put this in my `authentication_pages_spec.rb`: `expect do put user_path(user), {user: {admin: 1}, id: user.id} end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)`

But it doesn't raise the error.  Should I be looking for a different error?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it I think you are acting as the client and it's the server that will raise the error. I think you might only be able to see a bad response. I believe the error code is 503.

Comment: My apologies, was doing something wrong elsewhere in my tests.  The `MassAssignmentSecurity` error is the one that's being raised (assuming I haven't made a mistake of course).